# All my functions get ignored, except the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I don't know how to get the other functions (on the top) to run, it only works with the last one.

My code:

```
function advance(rQ, desc, ec){
            $('.achieve').text(desc + ". " + 'Points: ' + ec);
            $('.achieve').append(desc + ". " + 'Points: ' + ec);
            $('.achieve').append(desc + ". " + 'Points: ' + ec);
        }

        advance(5, "Getting Started. Get 5 points", 1);
       advance(10, "No Longer a Rookie. Get 10 points", 1);
       advance(15, "More Than a Beginner. Get 15 points", 1);
       advance(20, "Getting The Hang of It! Get 20 points", 1);
       advance(30, "Beating the Average. Get 30 points", 2);
       advance(45, "More Than a Master. Get 45 points", 2);
       advance(50, "OG. Get 50 points", 1);
       advance(60, "Hacker. Get 60 points", 2);
       advance(90, "King of Twurkeys. Get 90 points", 3);
       advance(100, "Pro Hacker. Get 100 points", 2);
```

You can see, I was duplicating the append() function. I also did it to the text() function to.

Here's my site: https://venerable-dango-3de1ef.netlify.app/achieve.html.

Thanks

Comment: They all run, just each one *overwrites* the previous, leaving only the last.   The `.text()` of subsequent calls replaces the previous `.append`s

Comment: Oh, ok. How do I fix that?

Comment: Remove the `.text()` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the text. The text was overwriting the previous functions, only showing the last function. To fix that, just simply delete the text().